# fatal error: kdecoration.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, kde, make, kubuntu

I got the following error during the compilation of the [AuroraeDesigner](https://www.linux-apps.com/content/show.php?content=122763)  from source although I've installed `libkdecorations*` :

```
fatal error: kdecoration.h: No such file or directory
```

Kubuntu : 18.04 
KDE : 5.44

Comment: Edit the question to tell us more: What is the project? How are you building it? What gave the error?

Comment: KDE 5 : The new name is probably *kdecoration2/decoration.h* : `/usr/include/KDecoration2/kdecoration2/decoration.h` https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libkdecorations2-dev/filelist ... I.e. kdecoration.h is a KDE4 header.

Comment: @KnudLarsen The filename that exists in my "/usr/include" is exactly what you've mentioned.But that project always tries to include "kdecoration.h" somewhere which has no sense.I don't know why.

Comment: Finally I realized that "kdecoration.h" was a part of kde4 and I have kde5 installed.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file dose not exist. Maybe you need to add a library package, see list of dependencies for the project. If this does not answer your question then you need to add more detail.

Comment: The problem was that it required "kde4" (find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED) in CMakeLists.txt) package to be installed and since that's not present in ubuntu 18 repo, I need to install it from source.However I don't need that program anymore. Thanks